# How to log the server/database names that are being used by SSIS packages?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

Can someone help me with the below? I really appreciate it! 
Thank you very much in advance!

How to log the server/database names that are being used by SSIS packages?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a few ways. How I would do it is like so.

1. Create variables to store your data.
2. Use package configurations to map your variables to the database. This will allow you to change the values as you move environments by creating a script that sets the specific info by server name.
3. Write to a flat file destination of your choice the variable info.

Let me know if I need to clarify.